# Database error on election candidate info page

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

If you navigate to the [election page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election) and then visit any of the previous election pages and click on the [more information about the candidates](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#gaming.stackexchange), instead of showing the extra information, you get a Database Error saying, "Error establishing a database connection". I would imagine this has something to do with the recent change to using https.

Comment: I think we may have removed that link at some point between this being reported and now, no? I can't seem to find it anywhere, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294719/342074) about this.  To quote the answer:

> Yeah, this is gonna be down for a bit; Tim Stone was maintaining it
>   and Tim Post was hosting it. The domain, of course, was controlled by
>   the company... Which is currently moving all se.com subdomains to
>   HTTPS. This presents two problems:
>
> 1. Tim Post can't continue hosting it, and we don't have an internal
>      setup for hosting node.js apps.
> 2. We can't keep it on that domain.
>
> We're gonna try & figure something out, but don't expect it to be back for a
>   little while.